# Cannot passing data to views

Tags: php, laravel-8

I'm using laravel 8 to make pass data to views pages.

Unfortunately i have error saying ' Target class [PagesController] does not exist' on my browser

So here's my PagesController.php

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
public function index (){
$title = 'welcomeee to london';
return view ('pages.index',compact ('title'));
}
}
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('/index',[PagesController::class,'index']);
```

index.blade.php

```
<p> {{$title}}</p>
```

i want to pass the variable $title to index.blade.php but have error. Tried so many times but didn't work

Comment: Did you use your class in 'web.php'?

Comment: `use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PageController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
class PagesController extends Controller
{
public function index (){
$title = 'Laravel 8 is awesome';
return view('index', compact('title'));
}
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<p> {{  $title}}</p>
```

for   **web.php**

```
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\StudInsertController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
Route::get('/index',[PagesController::class,'index']);
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a file index.blade.php under views... like this as i have shown in figure....

Comment: please try to clear the cache also by running php artisan view:clear

Comment: my index file under pages... resources/views/pages/index.blade

Comment: try this then return view ('pages.index',compact ('title')); PageController.php

Comment: its worksss thank you so much :D god bless

Answer (score 0):

in the controller when you assign a view, you can assign one or multiple variables to the view.

Exemple:

```
public function index()
{
    $title = 'List of my pictures';
    $images = Image::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);

    return view('home',[
        'images' => $images,
        'title', => $title
    ]);
}
```